# show facebook like count only

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Does facebook provide any widget to show just the "Like" count (i.e. somehow hide/not include the "Like" button) ?

Or this needs to be done using fql only?

Answer (score 1):

if you use the graph API, you can easily get the details of a page including the number of likes. example: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola, but if you want the count of any webpage with a likebox (that's not an actual page), I suggest you resize the iframe with CSS to just show the count (if that's what you want). It's not pretty, but It'll do the trick...